# Solving binomial distribution question in R language

Tags: r

Insurance policies are sold to 10 different people age 25-30 years. All of these are in good health
conditions. The probability that a person of similar condition will enjoy more than 25 years is 4/5. Calculate the probability that in 25 years Almost 2 will die. Perform this calculation in R syntax without using any direct built-in function.

```
n <- 10
p_live <- 4/5
p_notlive <- 0.2
Pzerodie <- combn(n,0)*(p_live^0)*(p_notlive^n-0)
print(Pzerodie)
```

I will do the same process for P(one die) and P(two die) and then add all three variable. Now the above code should print 1.024 * 10^-7 for P(Pzerodie)! But its printing : [,1]. Can anyone guide? Thanks

Comment: `?combn` says "Generate all combinations of the elements of x taken m at a time". Eg `combn(10, 1)` returns 10 columns 1:10. `combn(10, 2)` returns 45 columns of (1,2), (1,3), ... ,(9,10) ie all the distinct combinations. I think it might be `combn(10, 2)` you want - ie the combinations of the 2 out the 10 people who could die. take `ncol(combn(10, 2))` to get this value. Then use `2` and `10-2` in the formula.

Comment: I don't think `combn` does what you think it does. Did you mean `choose` ?

Comment: @JonnyPhelps Thanks for replying! So you are saying that I am doing it wrong mathematicaly too. It said "Almost 2 will die". So i think that I will have to do P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(X=2) . Am i wrong?

Comment: At the risk of doing your homework, I would ask if `combn()` and `choose()` are "direct built-in functions".

Comment: yeah true I'd say they are direct built-in functions

Comment: I think if your question is find the probability that up to 2 people will die, then your logic is ok, but @G5W is right that using `choose(10, 0)` should work in that formula, and then you can add them up. So I'd work to finding the solution with `choose` and sense-check it's right, then try to figure out how to replicate `choose`. I think visualising `combn` outputs can help with that

Comment: @the-mad-statter  How can I do this without using combn() ?Because its a built in function!

Comment: @JonnyPhelps Do you know any other way we can do this without using combn()?

Comment: I can use factorial() and somehow calculate the answer but again factorial() is also a built in function. Isn't this a stupid requirement not to use direct built-in function.?